# How to fix Android AVD problem in windows 10

Tags: android, windows-10, android-virtual-device

I installed HAXM, disabled Hyper-V, disabled Microsoft Security, disabled UAC and enabled VT but my AVD show blank(transparent) screen.

what should i do?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: is it a problem with all emulators?

Comment: @Narendra_Nath i installed NOX, but it has this problem most times but genymotion is a bit better.

Comment: Try this 
    Tools > AVD Manager
    Select virtual device
    Click on Edit (pencil icon for me)
    Click "Show Advanced Settings"
    Look for Emulated Performance - Graphics
    Select the "Software" option
Choose the one which does not have a play store icon

Comment: @Narendra_Nath Graphics dropdown is disabled and has been set on Automatic

Answer (score 0):

If the Android Emulator does not start properly, this problem is often caused by problems with HAXM. HAXM issues are often the result of conflicts with other virtualization technologies, incorrect settings, or an out-of-date HAXM driver. Try reinstalling the HAXM driver, using the steps detailed in Installing HAXM

Comment: i installed last version(7.6.5) of HAXM and my laptop has all of requirement of HAXM. see this [screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/K287iIH.jpg)